# Nameserver update for AWS EC2 hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, nameservers

I have deployed a simple html website running on NGINX on a AWS EC2 server. I intend to host 2-3 static websites on this server. For the time being, I have configured only 1 server block and hosted the website.

When I type the ip address/public dns name of the server in the browser, I can see my website. My domain name is registered with another service provider.

How should I update the Nameserver records in my domain registrar account? Should I just update the public ip address in the name server field or should I update the public dns name?

My domain registrar is asking for two name server details as compulsory fields. If I update the same public ip address twice, its not allowing me to save.

Please advise. I want to know the nameserver details for my EC2 based website. My website is not hosted on Amazon Route53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not update your nameserver records, these are records you would use to configure where your DNS records should be resolved.

Instead you need to update/create an A record that points from the domain to your new host IP.